# As for a random position inside the area

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

How do I modify the code so that the character randomly changes position inside the green area when the game starts? I don't know how to find the minimum and maximum values of the X and Z coordinates of this green area. Sorry for the bad English and thank you for the advice and help
[image]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class randomzombieposition : MonoBehaviour {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    Vector3 pos;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        x = Random.Range(17,18);
        y = 0;
        z = Random.Range(25,46);
        pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to determine boundaries for shaped like this. Therefore you can split this into sub-zones. First you can choose a random zone after that you can produce random position in that zone.

[image: This is just an example of sub-zones]

Answer (score 0):

You can use physics [raycasts](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) with a [mesh collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) and the collider's [bounding box](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html) to automatically generate different positions on your play field. I don't have a script ready to show this technique right now, but you can read more on that topic in a [recent thread in the Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/spawn-random-objects-inside-the-mesh-collider-area.925448/). - It is also possible to approximate your floor with regular colliders like box colliders or sphere colliders.

When you want to use that technique, it can be helpful to set the [layer mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) parameter accordingly for your raycast calls to ignore other colliders in the scene, that are not part of the floor.

Maybe, it is also interesting for you to also have a look into [Unity's path finding docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this so far. I created points that were placed on the green area, I used this code. Any other solution?

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class random5 : MonoBehaviour {
    
        public GameObject[] wayPoints;
        public GameObject enemy;
    
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            if (wayPoints.Length > 0) {
                int nr = Random.Range(0, wayPoints.Length);
                GameObject waypoint = wayPoints[nr];
                Vector3 pos = waypoint.transform.position;
                enemy.transform.position = pos;
                Debug.Log("point: "+waypoint.name+", coordinates: "+pos);
            }
        }
        
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that way you will have full control over all possible "way points", that's a good solution when there's no need to select the positions fully randomly and gives more control of the starting conditions. This way, you could also manually set the rotation of the transforms in the Unity editor, and use it to orient the object. - To make things a bit more readable, I've edit your solution a bit, hope that's okay.